HTMX and flowbite charts
I have a problem with HTMX and tailwind (flowbite) components. I have a sidebar where i can change panels through htmx request
 <a  href="#" hx-get="/dashboard" hx-target="#space" hx-trigger="load,click"  class="flex items-center p-2 text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 group">


and i want to have a chart in a different page and when i change this page from dashboard the chart cant render (but when i type /chart in browser url the chart is rendering well so it isnt problem)
templ C1(s []int){

        <div id="area-chart"></div>
            @templ.JSONScript("chart-data", s)

            <script>
                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                    const chartData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('chart-data').textContent);

                    const options = {
                               ....

                    if (document.getElementById("area-chart") && typeof ApexCharts !== 'undefined') {
                        const chart = new ApexCharts(document.getElementById("area-chart"), options);
                        chart.render();
                    }
                });
            </script>

}


       <script>
           htmx.onLoad(function(content) {
               initFlowbite();
           })
       </script>

maybe here i have to add something

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
